# Creating all lists of length "n" from a list of q elements

Tags: python, list, sage

For a couple of days I've been trying to find a way to create all lists of length "n" from a list of "q" elements. So far I've been able to get sage to print all of the lists I'm looking to obtain. However, since I need these lists for another program I need my program to output a list of all of these lists instead of just having Sage print the lists. What I have so far is:

```
def XUniv(q,x,n):
    """
    :param q: is your alphabet size
    :param x: is a zero vector of any length
    :param n: is len(x)-1
    """
    for i in range(q):
        x[n]=i
        if n==0:
            print x
        else:
            XUniv(q,x,n-1)
```

Comment: Kind of unclear question. Do you want all permutations of q integers up to a fixed length n?

Comment: No. Lets say q=2 and n=3 then I want my function to output [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]

Comment: Okay, so permutations of fixed length n of integers less than q.

Comment: Exactly. Like i said in the question my current function will print what I'm looking for but I need a way to put all of the printed objects into a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is something like this what you want?

```
sage: q=1
sage: n=3
sage: L = IntegerListsLex(min_part=0, max_part=q, length=n)
sage: list(L)
[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Without Sage:

```
import itertools
def all_lists_from_q_elements(q, n):
    all_lists_iter = itertools.product(tuple(range(q)), repeat=n)
    return [list(l) for l in all_lists_iter]
```

Comment: This doesn't return all permutations, so for example the result contains `(0, 0, 1)`, but not `(1, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Yes, I used the wrong function :\ It's fixed now.